# How to use React Router Link on a landing page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am still learning and am fairly confused with documentation and other SO questions that use Link in order to accomplish my goal of routing through my site on click from the landing page. I have circled back a few times fitting these concepts together and haven't yet figured out what I've done wrong.

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header/Header';
import Landing from './Components/Landing/Landing';
import Map from './Components/Map/Map';
import Footer from './Components/Footer/Footer';
import Contact from './Components/Contact/Contact';
import Questions from './Components/Questions/Questions';
import Error from './Components/Error/Error';
import {
  Router,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Route path="/Landing" component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/Map" component={Map} />
        <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/Questions" component={Questions} />
        <Route path="/Error" component={Error} />
        <Route path="/" component={Landing} />
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Sample of Landing.jsx

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Landing extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <div className="Landing">
          <h4 className="Landing-Find">
            <Link to="/Map">
              Find Your Screening Center
            </Link>
            <FontAwesomeIcon
                      icon={faSearch}
                      size="1x"
                      id="icon"
            />
          </h4>
          <h4 className="Landing-Contact">
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hack",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^1.12.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-drawers": "^1.4.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "testing-library": "^0.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "use-places-autocomplete": "^1.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My current error is:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined.

**I'll keep hacking and thanks!**

Comment: You should not have multiple routers nested under each other. I think the `<Router>` in your App component was probably intended to be a `<Switch>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add:

```
  BrowserRouter as Router
```

instead of

```
import {
  Router,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
```

into App.js for my routing to work.

Comment: You already have a `<BrowserRouter>` in the index.js.

Comment: I took it out again when I looked at the documentation. https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic